# Could not parse the remainder in template

Tags: python, mysql, django

This is my DjangoTemplates/(mysite)/index.html. I'm trying to do some math in my index.html. I want to display the sum of the entire Stakes.amount_won for each user_name in the for loop. I think I have the syntax correct for the math, but it does not seem to work in the template.

The for loop should go through each user_name, and display their user_name as a link with the Amount Won: (total of amount_won for that user_name) below.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

<h1> Players </h1>

{% if latest_player_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for player in latest_player_list %}
        <li><a href="/stakeme/{{ player.id }}/">{{ player.user_name }} </a><br>Total Won: {{Stakes.objects.filter(player__user_name).aggregate(Sum('amount_won'))}}
</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <br>
{% else %}
    <p>No players are available.</p>
{% endif %}

<h3><a href="/stakeme/new/">New Player</a></h3>
```

Sorry if this is noobish. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the import statement is not part of the template language, this isn't actually your problem - it will just show as text. The actual problem is your function call: Django doesn't allow calls with parentheses in templates. Only functions with no parameters are allowed. You need to do the lookup in the view and pass it in the context.

Of course, this is all [clearly explained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls) in the documentation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I appreciate you linking to the documentation rather than saying RTFM. This may be over my head, as I've grasped the concept that it needs to be in the view - but I still can't get it to work - the form just reads Amount Won: and then is blank from there.

    `def index(request):
        latest_player_list = Player.objects.all().order_by('id')[:20]
        return render_to_response('stakeme/index.html', {'latest_player_list': latest_player_list})
        total_amount_won = Stakes.objects.filter(player__user_name).aggregate(Sum('amount_won'))
        return total`

Comment: and the form:

`<h1> Players </h1>

{% if latest_player_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for player in latest_player_list %}
        <li><a href="/stakeme/{{ player.id }}/">{{ player.user_name }} </a><br>Total Won: {{ total_amount_won }}
</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <br>
{% else %}
    <p>No players are available.</p>
{% endif %}

<h3><a href="/stakeme/new/">New Player</a></h3>`

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer here is that you're trying to do too much in the template - for example, you can't use a Python `import` statement in a template at all, so I imagine that's just rendering as text. What you'd generally want here is to do the query logic in your view class, then pass the data to the template for rendering.

Comment: I see. I'm actually not sure if it's rendering as text or not as I added both the import statement and the query logic at the same time - and receive the "Could not parse the remainder." I will take a look at the docs to see if I can find any information about adding this to the view instead. Thank you.